# i have a part of code that works in git bash but not when i make a script out of it

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

Hello awesome community i am using git bash to run this command: `cp -r thisfolder thatfolder` to copy the contents of a folder in another one

now i want to make a script out of this to create a scheduler to run that script and my script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t

cp -r thisfolder thatfolder && echo done > debug.txt 
#the debug.txt is just to know if the script copied stuff
```

its a .bat script and all folders and script are on the same directory but for some reason it doesnt copy the files as git bash does

any thoughts??

Comment: If it's a `.bat` script, it won't get run by bash, it'll get run by Window's cmd/batch file interpreter. Actually, I guess it depends how your launch it. Can you show how you invoke this script exactly?

Comment: If it is running as a bash script, having the folders in the same directory as the script is irrelevant; the working directory of shell scripts is inherited from whatever ran the script, not the location of the script itself. See [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within).

Comment: i double click on it tbh. what changes can i do if i want to make this work either as a .bat or a .sh(i tried making it as a .sh and running it from git bash but still get no results)

Comment: i also tried copy command and when i run it with powershell it works when i add it in the .bat and double click it it doesnt can someone explain pls?

Comment: quotes are not balanced